# Use Selected Option for SQL-Query (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause, dropdown

I have a database that contains three columns: idKernfragen; Kernfrage; Gebiet

I'd like to set up a Dropdown-List with the options from "Gebiet" - this is working fine. I also managed to SELECT all the information from the database. However, I'd like to use the selected option from the Dropdown as a variable and add "WHERE" to my SQL-Query to only display where 'Gebiet'=Dropdown-Selection.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
$db = mysqli_connect (
                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                     MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                     MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                     MYSQL_DATENBANK
                    );
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="select">
    <select name="gebiet1" onchange="this.form.submit();">

<?php
$gebietausgabe = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT Gebiet FROM kernfragen");
while ($row = $gebietausgabe->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo "<option value=\"gebiet1\">" . $row['Gebiet'] . "</option>";
}

?>

    </select>
    </div>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<?php        
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idKernfragen, Kernfrage FROM kernfragen");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
  echo $row->idKernfragen;
  echo '.) ';
  echo $row->Kernfrage;
  print "<br>";
}
?>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use `where gebiet = $_POST['gebiet1']` in your query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gebiet1'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['gebiet1'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>

<?php
require_once ('config.php');
$db = mysqli_connect (
                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                     MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                     MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                     MYSQL_DATENBANK
                    );
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="select">
    <select name="gebiet1" onchange="this.form.submit();">

<?php
$gebietausgabe = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT Gebiet FROM kernfragen");
while ($row = $gebietausgabe->fetch_assoc())
{

  echo '<option value="' . $row['Gebiet'] . '">' . $row['Gebiet'] . '</option>';
}

?>

    </select>
    </div>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<?php        
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idKernfragen, Kernfrage FROM kernfragen where Gebiet='".$selected_val."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
  echo $row->idKernfragen;
  echo '.) ';
  echo $row->Kernfrage;
  print "<br>";
}
?>
```